# Angular5 - Poll JSON with HttpClient

Tags: angular, http, angular5

I use Angular5 with HttpClient in a service. My service (thanks to Reza) is :

```
...
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMapTo';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
export interface Spot {
    lat: number,
    lng: number,
    spotname: sring
}
tempspots: <Spot[]>
@Injectable()
export class SpotService {
   private spoturl = '<JSON SERVICE URL>';
   constructor(
      private http: HttpClient,
      ...
   ) {}
   onGetBoundsSpots(minlat, maxlat) : Observable<Spot[]> {
      return 
       Observable.timer(0, 10000).mergeMapTo(  // ADDED TO POLL every 10 sec
       this.http
      .get<Spot[]>(this.spoturl)
       )   // ADDED TO POLL
      .map(spots => {
         return spots.filter(spot => { 
            return spot.lat > minlat && spot.lat < maxlat;
         })
      })
   }
}
```

This works fine WITHOUT POLLING

BUT I want to poll this service every 10 seconds. So I added above the // ADDED TO POLL

PROBLEM : When I display these infos (_restrictspots) in the html template, the _restrictspots change at each polling from all spots (without filter) to only spots filtered : this takes a few seconds to filtered the spots and the spots are displayed during this process.

Of course, I want to display ONLY THE FILTERED SPOTS... To display the filtered spots only at ??? OnComplete ??? something like this.

My component :

```
import { SpotService, Spot } from '../../../shared/spot/spot.service
@Component({
...
template: '<div>Count : {{ _restrictspots.length }}</div>
  <div *ngFor="let spot of _restrictspots" ><p>{{ spot.spotname }}</p></div>
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" 
  (boundsChange)="boundsChange($event)"</agm-map>',
  ...
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
   lat: number = 50;
   lng: number = 4;
   zoom: number = 12;
   constructor(private spotserv: SpotService) {}
   onRestrictBounds(bounds) {
      this.spotserv.onGetBoundsSpots(bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),bounds.getNorthEast().lat()).
      subscribe(
         resarray => {
           this._restrictspots = resarray;
         }
      )
   }
   boundsChange(bounds) {
     this.onRestrictBounds(bounds);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
   }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide your HTML-Template too. And please show us your onGetBoundsSpots(bounds)-method of your SpotService. Because you do not call the above provided onRestrictBounds(minlat, maxlat)-method but onGetBoundsSpots(bounds). Is this a typo or on purpose?

Comment: I updated my code to add all features.

Comment: Trivially: `Observable.interval(10000).map(() => service.get(params))`

Comment: Thanks for the update. But still the code you provide is not concise. In your SpotService you show the method `onRestrictBounds(minlat, maxlat): Observable<Spot[]> {}` but in your SidebarComponent you obviously subscribe to `onGetBoundsSpots(minlat, maxlat): Observable<Spot[]> {}`. The methods have different names. Is this a typo or copy-and-past-mistake or do actually both methods exist? Seeing this I'd reckon that you subscribe to the wrong method and don't recognize it...

Comment: You are right. This is a mistake. Both are the same : onGetBoundsSpots. Sorry. Correction done in above code.